# homeplug network

Tags: powerline-networking

I am moving to a new house and my home office will be located on the second floor. Since it's a rental, I can't run a CAT-5E or CAT-6 network cable from the router to my office and I was considering going with the [Power-Line-Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication) solution. Wireless technology has evolved a lot, but I still rather have a wired connection for work.

I understand that, ideally, I should have the same circuit for better network efficiency, but that's not an option here. On the circuit breaker board, there's one breaker for the downstairs power outlets and one for the upstairs.

Would PLC work in this case? Is there any foreseeable caveat on this scenario?

Comment: Did you ask the landlord if you could add that wire?

Comment: Ideal for powerline networking is everything on the same breaker.  The farther you deviate from that, the less reliable it is and the slower it is.  The only way to really know how it will perform in your setup is to try it.  BTW, there are similar modules for networking on your telephone lines (assuming the house is wired for a land line).  You don't mention why you prefer a wired solution for your business.  Two reasons I can think of are speed and security.  You may actually get more of both with a wireless LAN.  Speed depends on your situation.  (cont'd)

Comment: Wireless can have better security.  The powerline signal permeates through the power grid for surprising distances.  Even when the signal is poor enough to cause you frustration in your own house, hackers can pick it up farther away than WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a powerline network adapter on a power strip (contrary to recommended practice) which is on a different breaker than the other adapter, which is connected directly to an outlet.

It has been working well enough over time, although I have had to twice in one year reset the system by unplugging each one in turn to re-establish the connection.

You ask about caveats. The worst case situation I see is that one breaker pops and you have to reset the breaker, then power cycle each module. For that reason, access to the modules should be high on your list of considerations.